# Problemas ao remover os itens de uma List<ViewModel> quando a row é removida usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma lista de contatos que é carregada dinamicamente usando o razor e Javascript para remover as linhas e reordenar as posições dos campos. O problema ocorre quando eu clico no botão excluir registro e deleto todos os contatos (Eu envio uma requisição ajax para o banco e deleto todos), na tela eles desaparecem, mas a List no qual foi feito o Binding continua carregada com registros zerados e nulos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu salvar e dar post, a list vem carregada com os os itens zerados e nulos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que os registros da List não são excluídos? Será que é algum problema com a ordem dos índices dos fields? Existe uma maneira de resolver isso?

//CONTROLLER (EXCLUSÃO USANDO AJAX)

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-contato/remover-pessoa-contato/{id:int}")]
public void DeletePessoaContato(int id)
{
    _pessoaContatoAppService.Remove(id);
}
```

FONTE COMPLETO:

```
@model Retaguarda.Application.ViewModels.Pessoa.PessoaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_PessoaContato";
}
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-contatos">

                @if (Model.PessoasContatosViewModel != null)
                {
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PessoasContatosViewModel.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="form-group row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].PessoaId, new { @class = "hid-pessoaId" })                                
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
                                <select asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" asp-items="Model.ContatosTipos" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="text-danger sel-contatoTipo"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
                                <input type="text" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Contato" class="text-danger txt-contato"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
                                <textarea asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes"></textarea>
                                <span asp-validation-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="text-danger txt-detalhes"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                    <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" autocomplete="off" />
                                    <label asp-for="PessoasContatosViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" data-id="@Model.PessoasContatosViewModel[i].Id" style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }

                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button id="btn-add-contato" type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline"><i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Novo Contato</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
        $(function () {

            var qtdContatos = $("#div-contatos input.txt-contato").length;

            $("#btn-add-contato").click(function (e) {
                var novoIndice = qtdContatos;
                e.preventDefault();
                $.get("/pessoa-contato-gerenciar/getPessoaContato/" + novoIndice, function (data) {                    
                    $("#div-contatos").append(data);
                    qtdContatos++;
                });
            });

            $("#div-contatos").on("click", ".btn-remover-contato", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

                if (id)
                    $.post("/pessoa-contato/remover-pessoa-contato/" + id);

                $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //Para remover o Panel e não dar problema, tem que add mais um Parent()
                qtdContatos--;

                $("#div-contatos .row").each(function (indice, elemento) {
                    $(elemento).find(".sel-contatoTipo").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].ContatoTipoId");
                    $(elemento).find(".txt-contato").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].Contato");
                    $(elemento).find(".ckb-contatoPrincipal").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].ContatoPrincipal");
                    $(elemento).find(".txt-detalhes").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].Detalhes");


                    $(elemento).find(".hid-id").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].Id");
                    $(elemento).find(".hid-pessoaId").attr("name", "PessoasContatosViewModel[" + indice + "].PessoaId");
                });
            });
        });
</script>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consegui entender em que momento esses dados ficam nulos

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, quando eu add row por row eu inspeciono cada input e os índices  ficam certos e a medida que removo-os eles são decrementados corretamente... Não entendo pq isso está acontecendo....:(

Comment: Adiciona o exemplo do html renderizado através da adição de um novo. No caso da pergunta, você colocou todas as informações, menos as relevantes ao problema

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, add uma imagem inspecionando a primeira row adicionada. O Índice está 0.

Comment: E você já não tem outro conjunto com índice 0?

Comment: Pelo que inspecionei, não. A medida que adiciono uma row, seu índice é incrementado ex: 0, 1, 2, 3..... Se eu inspecionar todas as rows, elas estão com essas ordens sem repetições

Comment: Pera... você está adicionando uma nova pessoa ou apenas contatos?

Comment: Dentro da minha pessoaviewmodel tenho uma lista de pessoacontato . Não posso receber apenas uma lista de contatos, pois é um relacionamento de 1 : N.  O que faço eh receber a pessoaviewmodel carregada com os dados do banco e fazer um for para criar dinamicamente as robson de contatos. E o problema me parece ser exatamente aí, pois ao remover uma Rowling a list continua com os itens vazios.. quando add uma nova Rowling e removo parece funcionar.